# How to pass async await response to Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

Hi I would like to ask some question,
I am using async await on my page to load a series of images and my problem is I am unable to pass the response from my async function.

Here's my code:
In my page view I have a loop of items:

```
<div class="grid-x" v-for="(item, index) in cart_item_list">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x cart-summary">
            <div class="cell large-3 small-4 shrink cart-summary-image-container">
                {% comment %} <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/96x96.png" @click="processCartSummaryImage(item.product_details.images)" /> {% endcomment %}
                <img :src="processCartSummaryImage(item.product_details)" />
                <div style="display:none">Product ID: !! item.product_details.id !!</div>
                <div style="display:none">Parent Product SKU: !! item.product_details.properties.parent_product_sku !!</div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then I am calling this function **processCartSummaryImage** passing the details I needed on my async function

then on scripting I am accessing these methods

```
getProductImage: async function(sku) {
    return await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `/api/cart/get_product_main_detail.json?filter_sku=${ sku }`
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        //console.log('resp: ', response.data.response.image_1.url);
        return response.data.response.image_1.url;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        //console.log(error);
        return placeholder;
    });
},
processCartSummaryImage: async function(product_detail) {

    var placeholder = "https://via.placeholder.com/96x96.png";
    var sku = "";
    var set_image = "";

    // check if parent_slug_sku is available if not use the current slug
    if(product_detail.properties.parent_product_sku != "") {
      sku = product_detail.properties.parent_product_sku;
    } else {
      sku = product_detail.properties.sku;
    }

    try {
      const resp = await this.getProductImage(sku);
      console.log('response data:', resp);
      return resp; // PROBLEM IS IT DOESN'T PASS ON MY IMG SRC
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

},
```

Here's the result of the console log
https://cbo.d.pr/i7h4wV

And on my img source I am getting Object Promise only
https://cbo.d.pr/4ShOK3

Can you help me on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load image src url in vuejs asyncronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659676/how-to-load-image-src-url-in-vuejs-asyncronously)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `await` and `.then`. `.then` is used to run something after a promise has resolved, but you're already awaiting it.

```
getProductImage: async function(sku) {
  return await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `/api/cart/get_product_main_detail.json?filter_sku=${ sku }`
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    //console.log('resp: ', response.data.response.image_1.url);
    return response.data.response.image_1.url;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    //console.log(error);
    return placeholder;
  });
},
```

Try changing the above to the below.

```
getProductImage: async function(sku) {
  try 
  {
    let response = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `/api/cart/get_product_main_detail.json?filter_sku=${ sku }`
    });

    return response.data.response.image_1.url;
  }
  catch(error) {
    return placeholder;
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still learning this kind of method I am glad you can help me identify my error. :)

Comment: I am still getting the same result. :(

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your problem. What you're trying to isn't possible in it's current form as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659676/how-to-load-image-src-url-in-vuejs-asyncronously). You could get all the images on `mounted` and add them to the `item` in `cart_item_list` or make your own component.